# Rails: parsing bad date data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to parse a list of dates in varying formats:

```
dates = ['01:00pm  06/03/2015', '03:30pm 05/28/2015', '0900am 06/13/2015', '0300pm 06/02/2015', '0300pm06/02/2015', '03:30pm 28/01/2015']
```

The list goes on. Essentially I need to make sense of any date and time that can be typed into a text field. I have no control over the data source in this respect. What can I do to help here? Some giant regex method?

So far I've got a valid date method check like so:

```
def valid_date(date)
  Date.valid_date?(*date.split('/').reverse.map(&:to_i))
end
```

I'm thinking I should at first split the date and time, especially since some people submit data without spaces. How can I tackle this *huge* problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [mojombo/chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem. But honestly, you have a really hard problem to solve. If none of the dates are structured then you are really doing your best guess to parse it. I am not sure what your requirements are, but I suggest fixing the data. With chronic gem, at least it gets you almost there. You can even do things like `"this tuesday 5:00"` or `"2 days ago"`

Comment: Great, I was hoping someone would have a library or gem with better interpretive features than what Rails comes with. Yeah, it's an uphill battle, I know, but it's gotta be done. Thanks!